# Fix CSS to word-wrap code blocks when printing

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, design

When printing a Stack Overflow page, code blocks with long lines of text can get truncated.  Truncated code blocks, even if they have scrollbars, don't do much good on paper.

The [root cause](https://superuser.com/a/802152/31983) is that the Stack Overflow stylesheet lacks a rule

```
@media print {
    pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
}
```

that is present on some other Stack Exchange sites.

Could the Stack Overflow stylesheet have that rule added?

Comment: Wow, do people really print out Stack Overflow pages? That seems so wasteful...

Comment: @CodyGray Saving as PDF for offline viewing sometimes include virtual printers. Even if no real printing is involved It's still printing.

Comment: @JaDogg Wait… you go *offline*?!

Comment: problem is not if the users want to take a printout or not, it's a feature that can improve the user experience, and seems easy to implement, therefore it's a good request

Comment: YES! Fixing this bug would help with [RFC1149](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1149.txt) compliance -- a very important thing in this modern age. Welcome to the 19th century, Stack Overflow!

Comment: Sounds to me like something that's easy to implement and not intrusive to anyone who doesn't want to print (paper or PDF) while potentially being useful to those who do wish to print something. Sure, the indentation would be screwed up but that's still better than truncated.

Comment: Since you say it is implemented in other sites, why not also in SO? Here, have my +1.

Comment: Strange, but true: there are still computers that are NOT connected to the internet and to which you cannot connect a USB drive or other media, so sometimes you just gotta print.

Comment: @Dale How would you access Stack Overflow with no internet or portable media?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Find the solution to the problem on SO.  Print the page.  Take the printed page into the secure area where all electronic communication in and out is tightly controlled.  Read the paper and use the information to fix the code.   Shred the paper because it's been in the secure area.

Comment: @Dale *<facepalm>* Of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this up. I've added the following CSS to all sites:

```
@media print {
    pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
}
```

This will make the `<pre>` block text word-wrap for printing only, but leave it as-is for regular site display. This will be live in the next prod build (meta: > `rev 2014.9.24.2604`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.24.1891`).