# Fix CSS to word-break code blocks when printing

Tags: feature-request, bug, design

Similiar to this post: [Fix CSS to word-wrap code blocks when printing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269627/fix-css-to-word-wrap-code-blocks-when-printing), can we have also:

```
@media print {
    pre {
        word-break: break-word;
    }
}
```

Currently, if there's a long, unspaced string in a row, it gets truncated in print mode. The most likely example for this truncation is when people ask json-related questions, and use an unspaced json.

For example, the following gets truncated on print mode:

```
["Lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet","consectetur","elit","sed","do","eiusmod","tempor","incididunt","labore","et","dolore","magna","aliqua"]
```

Comment: Possibly related to title break regressing: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376921/please-break-titles-on-words-not-letters/377076#comment772948_377076